# mysql psuedo column in where cluse

Tags: mysql

At present the `status` column in all rows is 0 and the `startdate` is at least several days previous to `now()`  but the following query returns an empty result set.

```
     select p.id, (select @days:=(datediff(now(),p.startdate))) as days from poa p 
     where p.status < @days;
```

Where might I be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id , days FROM 
( 
SELECT p.id as id , datediff(now(),p.startdate) as days  , p.status as status 
FROM poa p 
) 
t WHERE t.status < t.days;
```